# How to run loop in JavaFX by element

Tags: java, javafx

I've made 1 function in JavaFX I'm new in java don't know much functions about it and maybe its a silly question but what I did is I made 1 function which do a http call to google and get its response I found the result structure and select it but its a full string of 10 records I want all 10 records separate for example record is

```
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://in.linkedin.com/in/mohitbumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CBsQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNH6e1bxBXMBvQc2a6_AuNLt-OXc7Q"><b>Mohit Bumb</b> - India | LinkedIn</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>in.linkedin.com/in/<b>mohitbumb</b></cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CBwQ7B0wAA" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/search?q=related:in.linkedin.com/in/mohitbumb+mohit+bumb&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CB4QHzAA">Similar</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="f slp">
   Ujjain, Madhya Pradesh, India&nbsp;-&nbsp;CTO at SITS SolutionS
  </div>
  <span class="st">View <b>Mohit Bumb's</b> (India) professional profile on LinkedIn. LinkedIn is the <br /> world's largest business network, helping professionals like <b>Mohit Bumb</b> discover<br /> &nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/users/1470999/mohit-bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CCEQFjAB&amp;usg=AFQjCNHmVEhw0qLf4t0oKUTOJU2mQduF0g">User <b>Mohit Bumb</b> - Stack Overflow</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>stackoverflow.com/users/1470999/<b>mohit</b>-<b>bumb</b></cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CCIQ7B0wAQ" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:vvOM4noKbrEJ:http://stackoverflow.com/users/1470999/mohit-bumb%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CCQQIDAB&amp;usg=AFQjCNEeKzi1Yq3u-fvJ55M0agBomQJQ3w">Cached</a></li>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/search?q=related:stackoverflow.com/users/1470999/mohit-bumb+mohit+bumb&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CCUQHzAB">Similar</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st">Hello, I'm working as a Chief Technical Officer in a well known company at Ujjain. <br /> I've 3 years experience in web development field. I can perform any kind of&nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/mohitbumbrocks&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CCcQFjAC&amp;usg=AFQjCNEKABtg_Ri0VNyN9Ruv-TapxBskTQ"><b>MOHIT BUMB</b> ROCKS | Facebook</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>https://www.facebook.com/<b>mohitbumb</b>rocks</cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CCgQ7B0wAg" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:3Q2RQ_YbWHkJ:https://www.facebook.com/mohitbumbrocks%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CCoQIDAC&amp;usg=AFQjCNFwK_exvgqJjk7vdMQ17GMGU_i4DA">Cached</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st"><b>MOHIT BUMB</b> ROCKS, Ujjain, India. 2419 likes &middot; 4 talking about this. http://<br /> facebook.com/themohitbumb.</span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://profiles.wordpress.org/mohitbumb/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CCwQFjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNGadzF7Wasakh7nXeh0ds4Skt6-Pg">WordPress › Profiles &raquo; <b>Mohit Bumb</b></a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>profiles.wordpress.org/<b>mohitbumb</b>/</cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CC0Q7B0wAw" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:jGhtWnjmfzcJ:http://profiles.wordpress.org/mohitbumb/%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CC8QIDAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNGZ2esflGvt1byyG4llmYcH-ct9ZQ">Cached</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st">Location. This user has not filled out their location yet. <b>Mohit's</b> Plugins. WP <br /> Redirect Mobile. 1,731 downloads. <b>Mohit's</b> Activity. Replied to a topic in the WP.<br /> org&nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/images?q=mohit+bumb&amp;hl=en&amp;sa=X&amp;oi=image_result_group&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CDEQsAQ">Images for <b>mohit bumb</b></a></h3><br />
 <div>
  <a href="/url?q=https://twitter.com/RealMohitBumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CDMQ9QEwBA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHgvU2s23Y4WS4DaudpcyNTS0YMSg"><img height="89" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTKxylfoAi1mz3C_B2YXF09_irR33Rw1BOB_wGLrZCxKOfg8KR4JsBw0Q" width="89" align="middle" alt="" border="0" style="margin:3px 0;margin-right:6px;padding:0" /></a>
  <a href="/url?q=https://forums.digitalpoint.com/members/mohit-bumb.745047/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CDUQ9QEwBQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNHOD2CkMZuejaN3Q8JjLolnslsTiQ"><img height="87" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2lChwuKNMj0MXbsinykZjVQai03a25JuiLg9qXldcSJCPpt_DmPsexjY" width="65" align="middle" alt="" border="0" style="margin:3px 0;margin-right:6px;padding:0" /></a>
  <a href="/url?q=http://profiles.wordpress.org/mohitbumb-1/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CDcQ9QEwBg&amp;usg=AFQjCNG_bKvl-NhGiBUfQczFnqPs7ePC6Q"><img height="87" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhuf-oTUn-OZJBW_uS5va0l1UOgq_PlLKVLK6HBCDcdExdgkfWMWiUSJg" width="87" align="middle" alt="" border="0" style="margin:3px 0;margin-right:6px;padding:0" /></a>
  <a href="/url?q=https://twitter.com/real_mohit_bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CDkQ9QEwBw&amp;usg=AFQjCNFKJYwGmDZBllMQhmS9AdyzmcvlNQ"><img height="89" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmkdH2HGdLIVfldp4Y5y_kTV-5bzZsjXQyIA2OsZ86cQByBeT8l9Ar27Q" width="89" align="middle" alt="" border="0" style="margin:3px 0;margin-right:6px;padding:0" /></a>
  <a href="/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/users/863317/mohit-bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CDsQ9QEwCA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFg8cq-MbrcESnC_kS-tse-NmVrzA"><img height="87" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQY9PGwUKCMxKKYDwxKLRN6z5OZbI9NE9hIrJld6HaZ2PHWxPwRkmY8OhQ" width="87" align="middle" alt="" border="0" style="margin:3px 0;margin-right:6px;padding:0" /></a>
  <a href="/url?q=http://www.pinterest.com/liverockers/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CD0Q9QEwCQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNEFSmnPWGOJC_uMBMv8Cq54BIFfwA"><img height="87" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR5yce2XjPLEwVQrf0l4uHg6lX9eUMSWBsKNBdSPigoqKmW2ZJIM3JUi4" width="87" align="middle" alt="" border="0" style="margin:3px 0;margin-right:6px;padding:0" /></a>
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.crunchbase.com/person/mohit-bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CD8QFjAK&amp;usg=AFQjCNHCtisiZI9IAy53-_de2YCvXYX84A"><b>Mohit Bumb</b> | CrunchBase Profile</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>www.crunchbase.com/person/<b>mohit</b>-<b>bumb</b></cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CEAQ7B0wCg" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:kN1oPmwDcS8J:http://www.crunchbase.com/person/mohit-bumb%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CEIQIDAK&amp;usg=AFQjCNFSiUT5MMwG59ky6HaMjjVFoG2gmA">Cached</a></li>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/search?q=related:www.crunchbase.com/person/mohit-bumb+mohit+bumb&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CEMQHzAK">Similar</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st"><b>Mohit Bumb</b> is 18 years old sr. web developer at luutaa technologies, indore. <br /> He's also blogger and write articles on.</span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.guru.com/freelancers/Mohit-Bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CEUQFjAL&amp;usg=AFQjCNF6gPSxdtesnodXoSD4ah27ciz_Cw"><b>Mohit Bumb</b>, Indore, India, Web Developer, Website Designer, SEO <b>...</b></a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>www.guru.com/freelancers/<b>Mohit</b>-<b>Bumb</b></cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CEYQ7B0wCw" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:tK0v8zti9h4J:http://www.guru.com/freelancers/Mohit-Bumb%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CEgQIDAL&amp;usg=AFQjCNEfi9FiXNw3Iw_qELMh0PZvuoZFkw">Cached</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st">Find Web Developer -- <b>Mohit Bumb</b> (Indore, India) -- for Hire. Review This <br /> Freelancer's Qualifications, Reviews and Rate on Guru.com. Easily Contact for a <br /> Free&nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://twitter.com/real_mohit_bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CEoQFjAM&amp;usg=AFQjCNFKJYwGmDZBllMQhmS9AdyzmcvlNQ"><b>Mohit Bumb</b> (real_mohit_bumb) on Twitter</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>https://twitter.com/real_<b>mohit</b>_<b>bumb</b></cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CEsQ7B0wDA" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:dXxv0wr7bxgJ:https://twitter.com/real_mohit_bumb%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CE0QIDAM&amp;usg=AFQjCNFzYxvh_Eb_7kR3y6j9hj_a8x03_A">Cached</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st">The latest from <b>Mohit Bumb</b> (@real_mohit_bumb). i'm 17 years old boy studying <br /> private and designing website, some people already using my name here but&nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://twitter.com/RealMohitBumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CE8QFjAN&amp;usg=AFQjCNHgvU2s23Y4WS4DaudpcyNTS0YMSg"><b>Mohit Bumb</b> (RealMohitBumb) on Twitter</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>https://twitter.com/Real<b>MohitBumb</b></cite>
  </div>
  <span class="st">The latest from <b>Mohit Bumb</b> (@RealMohitBumb). I'm 18 years old web developer <br /> from Indore (Luutaa Technologies) and also doing bca from ujjain (Advance&nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://photobucket.com/images/MOHIT%2BBUMB%2BROCKS/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CFEQFjAO&amp;usg=AFQjCNGypIx7RMZ2u9WPobBFittoI8ljIw"><b>MOHIT BUMB</b> ROCKS Pictures, Images &amp; Photos | Photobucket</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>photobucket.com/images/<b>MOHIT</b>+<b>BUMB</b>+ROCKS/</cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CFIQ7B0wDg" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:BbkcFBNUQwMJ:http://photobucket.com/images/MOHIT%252BBUMB%252BROCKS/%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CFQQIDAO&amp;usg=AFQjCNHPoMqG3Fce5IRpz2zgNIzL5yXXDA">Cached</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st">View the 2 best <b>MOHIT BUMB</b> ROCKS Photos, <b>MOHIT BUMB</b> ROCKS Images, <br /> <b>MOHIT BUMB</b> ROCKS Pictures. Download photos or share to Facebook, Twitter,<br /> &nbsp;<b>...</b></span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
<li class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://math.stackexchange.com/users/15374/mohit-bumb&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CFYQFjAP&amp;usg=AFQjCNHh7JQzEdQQEiJeaF56lPs52UpPew">User <b>Mohit Bumb</b> - Mathematics Stack Exchange</a></h3>
 <div class="s">
  <div class="kv" style="margin-bottom:2px">
   <cite>math.stackexchange.com/users/15374/<b>mohit</b>-<b>bumb</b></cite>
   <div class="am-dwn-arw-container">
    ‎
    <div onclick="google.sham(this);" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" data-ved="0CFcQ7B0wDw" style="display:inline">
     <span class="am-dwn-arw"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="am-dropdown-menu" role="menu" tabindex="-1" style="display:none">
     <ul>
      <li class="am-dropdown-menu-item"><a class="am-dropdown-menu-item-text" href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:wkyfFmZMfdEJ:http://math.stackexchange.com/users/15374/mohit-bumb%252Bmohit%2Bbumb%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=4d_0UszCBI3yiAe9t4HwDQ&amp;ved=0CFkQIDAP&amp;usg=AFQjCNFesiYgW00uHQmrZWtb2GDIx-Rvig">Cached</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <span class="st">22 Oct 2013 <b>...</b> Hello, I'm working as a Chief Technical Officer in a well known company at Ujjain. <br /> I've 3 years experience in web development field.</span>
  <br />
 </div></li>
```

Its 10 li with class g but I want all it in sep. so I can show this li's according to me what I'm looking for is loop according to element class or all these elements in 1 array so I can write loop for it

Codes :

```
 private void callUrl(String keywords) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+URLEncoder.encode(keywords); 
        Document response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                            .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
        Elements records = response.select("body #ires li.g");
        //record = records.split(".g");
        System.out.println(records); System.exit(0);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it by myself

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+URLEncoder.encode(keywords); 
        Document response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                            .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
        Elements records = response.select("body #ires li.g");
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size()-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(records.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still trying to figure out a complete answer, and I am sorry to answer a question with another question.

I used two Patterns to find all the places where `<li>` and `</li>` are found.

```
//Your string
String bigString = "<div><li><div><li></li></div></li></div><li><div><li></li></div></li>";

Pattern li_start = Pattern.compile("<li>");  
Pattern li_end = Pattern.compile("</li>");

Matcher m_li_start = li_start.matcher(bigString);
Matcher m_li_end = li_end.matcher(bigString);

List<Integer> list_of_li = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list_of_li_close = new ArrayList<>();

    while (m_li_start.find()) {
        int index_of_li = m_li_start.start(); //finds 1st index of <li>
        list_of_li.add(index_of_li);
    }

    while (m_li_end.find()) {            
        int index_of_close_li = m_li_end.end(); //finds last index of </li>
        list_of_li_close.add(index_of_close_li);            
    }
```

When I print both list in the console I get the position of each `<li>` and `</li>`

```
[5, 14, 40, 49]    //all index of <li>
[13, 24, 42, 53]  //all last index of </li>
```

Now we know a combination of 1 item on each list is the answer you are looking for, in this case:

```
//print from [0,24] - 1st block of <li></li>
//print from [29,53] - 2nd block of <li></li>
```

Now how to get that answer still puzzles me, but I hope this helps you at least a little.
Again, sorry I couldn't help you with a better answer.

Comment: wow! your answer shows why i should read about records before hand XD, anyhow i am still a newbie :P